# Test Django with dictionary in dictionary data

Tags: python, django

### Description

I'm using Django for my website and trying to write some unit tests. However, when using dict in dict data I met some errors. I found out that `view` received slightly different data.

From
`{'class_id': '1', 'filter_options': {'full_name': 'user 1'}}` in data of test file
to `<QueryDict: {'class_id': ['1'], 'filter_options': ['full_name']}>`. I means that value has changed to array, and value of nested dict wasn't detected.

### Code

```py
# test.py
def test_search_with_full_name(self):
    data = {'class_id': '1', 'filter_options': {'full_name': 'user 1'}}
    response = self.client.post('/api/students', data, format='json')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

```py
# view.py
class SearchStudentView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        if not 'class_id' in request.data:
            return HttpResponse('class_id is required', status=400)

        class_id = request.data['class_id']

        students = Users.objects.filter(
            details_student_attend_class__course__pk=class_id)

        if 'filter_options' in request.data:
            filter_options = request.data['filter_options']

            if 'full_name' in filter_options:
                students = students.filter(
                    full_name=filter_options['full_name'])
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What test class are you using? `APITestCase`?

Comment: I'm using `TestCase` import from `django.test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `TestCase` uses `django.test.Client` as the client and it does not set the content type etc. according to the `format` kwarg, instead it uses the `content_type` kwarg so you should either set that or use `APITestCase` from DRF which will use the `APIClient` class.

While using `TestCase`:

```
def test_search_with_full_name(self):
    data = {'class_id': '1', 'filter_options': {'full_name': 'user 1'}}
    response = self.client.post('/api/students', data, content_type='application/json')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

While using `APITestCase` from DRF:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class YourTest(APITestCase):
    def test_search_with_full_name(self):
        data = {'class_id': '1', 'filter_options': {'full_name': 'user 1'}}
        response = self.client.post('/api/students', data, format='json')
    
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you change `format` to `content_type='application/json'`
[Django docs say this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/)

> If you provide content_type as application/json, the data is serialized using json.dumps() if it’s a dict, list, or tuple. Serialization is performed with DjangoJSONEncoder by default, and can be overridden by providing a json_encoder argument to Client. This serialization also happens for put(), patch(), and delete() requests.

---

There might be an issue with serializing the dictionaries as values for POST fields. So in case if above solution doesn't work another way could be a serialize filter options by your self using `json.dumps(filter_options)` before passing to the request. And then read them via `json.loads(request.POST.get(filter_options))` in your view.